Create a search bar in html which store search input as string
<i id="show"></i>//Out put will show here//

<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">//Search Bar//
<button value="submit" onclick="return test()" type="submit">Search</button>

<script>//Main function//
    function test(){

    var a = document.getElementById('search').value;
    var b = "Apple, Banana";

    for (var c = 0; c <= 1; c++) {
            
    if (a.innerHTML().match(b[c])){
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "You search " + "'" + b[c] + "'";           
    }
    else 
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "ERROR.";
            
    }
}
</script>

I am trying to create a search bar in html with 3 main functions. Store a search input as string(a), see if the string(a) and data(b) match or not, if match then show data and if not, show error. But I am not getting any output. I don't know where is error or maybe my whole code is wrong.

When you run your code, and something is wrong, your browser will generate an error message in the console. See: How to open the browser developer console. The error message will help you understand why your code doesn't work.

as long as b is string, so you're just matching the indexed letters, as c is between 0 and 1, so you are matching letters a or p in case sensitive

so var b = ["Apple"," Banana"];?

What am I missing?

Nevermind found it lol.

sure, using array will target each array element instead of letters, so ["apple", "banana"] will be considered as list of items so it will target apple as an element and banana as an element too,

wait match function not case insensitive?

You are missing several things.
First you need to parse your b string, to make array of strings ["Apple", "Banana"].
Second you are trying to call innerHTML() function on HTML input value, which you can't.
And third you have to return from function to stop for loop, when input string matches your data string.


function test(){
    var a = document.getElementById('search').value;
    var b = "Apple, Banana";
    var ar = b.split(", "); // arrray of strings ["Apple", "Banana"]

    for (var c = 0; c <= 1; c++) {
      if (a.match(ar[c])){ // no innerHTML function
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "You search " + "'" + ar[c] + "'";
        return; // return after match
      } else 
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "ERROR.";            
    }
}
<i id="show"></i>//Output will show here//

<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">//Search Bar//
<button value="submit" onclick="return test()" type="submit">Search</button>



